# Limiting Access of Technical User in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, privileges

My company has a single Apple account under which we develop several apps. I would like to add technical users to the account in iTunes Connect but want to limit each technical user's access, or at least "change" access, to specific applications.

Is there some way I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

no you can't  :(

iTunes connect  members will have a technical access to all your applications